# columnSelector Tablesorter width custom button

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I need show and hide the columns when I click on button.
like this:
[image]

but I want I want to show when the checkbox is selected.
[image]

My code is [This Demo][3]

Pls. Help Me!

[3]: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/115/`Help Me`

Comment: It isn't clear how the demo is different from what you want. Please tell us where you are getting stuck.